# SharePoint Search 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search

I have  document libraries  at each site collection level in SP2010 and we are migrating each site collection  one by one to SP2016 .

Now i'm building search in SP2016. we migrated our first Site Collection ,my question is can we get documents from SP2010 when I Search in SP2016,is there a way where we can link SP2010 repository to SP2016 Search?

I will search in Sp2016 i need to get documents from Sp2016 (which are migrated) and Sp2010(which are not migrated)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2016 will be able to crawl 2010 via a normal Content Source crawl. You will be able to search from 2016 to retrieve content from both 2010 and 2016.

SharePoint 2010 does not hook into SharePoint 2016 search. The native controls to perform searches in 2010 will only work against the search service on 2010.

Comment: Seward,i got the point .Can you elaborate the process how to get SP2010 results in SP2016. Do I need to create a new content source in Search Service Application and point that to SP2010?Can i Still scope the Search Result by content type for results i get from Sp2010 In Sp2016 Search Vertical.

Comment: Yes, create a new content source pointed at 2010. You'll have all of the same options in 2016 search for 2010 content with the exception of document previews.

Comment: Hi Seward can you help me with this  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256527/sharepoint-2016-managed-property-not-returning-values-in-search-hover-panel