# SharePoint 2016 Managed Property not returning values in Search Hover panel

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, display-template, managed-property

I have a Site Column "Doc Description" multiple line of text, added that in both list and library .Then Added few records in list&library published,created managed properties did full crawl and all.I created a custom Item display template and hover panel and want to display "Doc Description" column value.

Issue:I can see the "Doc Description" column value in Search results(For items from library) and same managed property returns null for Search results from list.

Reverse with Hithighlightedsummary ,i'm getting Hithighlightedsummary  value in search results for list items and null for items from library(tried adding managed property in Hithighlightedsummary json).

Comment: @Matthew McDermott can you help on this? getting managed property null for search results returned from list and getting highlighted value null for results returned form library.

Comment: Any luck? What are the results of your testing?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott No luck ,i tired re indexing the list and library and a full crawl. I diagnosed the "ctx" in search display template i see the description field value " " for items from library and Hit Highlighted property null for items from list .

Comment: You can use the Search Query tool to determine if the item was actually crawled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with basic troubleshooting.

1. Ensure that you have fresh content in both lists by adding new items to both the list and the library.
2. Use the SharePoint Search Query Tool (SPSQT) to query your content with KQL. Don't try the MP yet. Just be sure you are getting content from both. This will rule out permissions and syntax.
3. Add the MP to your query select fields. You should see the values returned in the results in the SPSQT. If this doesn't work there is no point in trying your Display Template.
4. Once 1-3 are working, look at your Item Display template mapping.
5. For hover panels your item must contain the mapping for your fields.
6. (On-Prem) If you are running on-prem you should also check the crawl logs all the way down to the item you are trying to troubleshoot. (This is not an option in SPO, but for the sake of others troubleshooting I thought I'd add it.)